# How to design rest api for reporting dashboard? Create all data required for reports in server side itself or manipulate data in UI?

Tags: rest, api

I have Reporting APIs in Spring and we display in a page, a table of records in React JS.
We have accounts table and transactions table. I have to query all accounts with a specific tag and their count of transactions by status, and display a dashboard with a table of data.

Should I design a REST API which queries data from accounts and transactions table, do data manipulation and send only the exact data required for display in react JS?

Or

Should I just make API calls to get accounts first, call transactions list next and create the data for the reports using lists and maps in client side itself?

Which is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the first option is much more suited. That is make a single REST api call and do everything related that is **query data from accounts and transactions table, do data manipulation and send only the exact data required for display in react JS**

This will be beneficial as making a REST call takes some time and making multiple REST calls means more time to update an info. on a page which is a bad user experience.

So in order to fast loading of a page I think first option is better.

Comment: REST calls can be made asynchronously. In the OP's context it does not seem possible but leaving the API as simple as possible (/accounts and /transactions) and the front do the math may sometimes be both easy and efficient. It also allows reusability.